# Color "not valid for the NSColor Generic Gray Gamma" when creating SKTexture from GKNoise with gradientColors

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, macos-big-sur, gameplay-kit

This basic code works until I try to add `gradientColors`:

```swift
let noise = GKNoise(src)
noise.gradientColors = [ 0.0: NSColor.blue, 0.5: NSColor.green, 0.75: NSColor.white]
let map = GKNoiseMap(noise,
                     size: vector_double2(x: inParams.noiseSize, y: inParams.noiseSize),
                     origin: vector_double2(x:0, y:0),
                     sampleCount: vector_int2(x: Int32(inParams.size), y:Int32(inParams.size)),
                     seamless: true)
let tex = SKTexture(noiseMap: map)
```

At which point I get the following in the Xcode console, upon creating the `SKTexture`:

```
*** -getRed:green:blue:alpha: not valid for the NSColor Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile colorspace 1 1; need to first convert colorspace.
```

Other people seem to be able to do this, so I’m not sure what I’m doing differently. I can’t figure out where I might set the color space.

macOS 11.3, Xcode 12.5, SwiftUI app.

Answer (score 4):

GameplayKit is invoking `getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)` on each of your `NSColor` instances behind the scenes, and according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1527848-getred), this method only works on colors in the `calibratedRGB` or `deviceRGB` color spaces (although it appears to also work for other spaces, like `sRGB`).

`NSColor.blue` and `NSColor.green` use `sRGB` by default, but `.white` uses `NSColorSpace.genericGray`. To convert:

```swift
let white = NSColor.white.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!
```

Alternatively, instantiating a color with its components directly, e.g. `NSColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)`, will put it in sRGB.